# php find element with class in array and print him

Tags: php, arrays, search

How do I find the `div` with specific class under `li` element in array and take it if it exists but with childs? I try `in_array`, `array_search` but nothing works.
I only need those elements that have a class " cf_sel_opt".

This PHP code

```
<div>
<?php
foreach ($filters_render_array['html'] as $key => $value) {
   if (strpos($key, 'custom_f_') !== false) {
      $selected[$key] = $value;
      print_r($selected[$key]);
   }
}
 ?>
</div>
```

Returns this HTML

```
<div>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/" class=" cf_sel_opt">
                <span></span>
            </a>
            <input name="custom_f_35[]" value="313038" type="hidden">
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/" class=" cf_sel_opt">
                <span></span>
            </a>
            <input name="custom_f_35[]" value="313034" type="hidden">
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/" class="">
                <span></span>
            </a>
            <input name="custom_f_35[]" value="313049" type="hidden">
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox">
                <a href="/">
                    7
                </a>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox">
                <a href="/">
                    6
                </a>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox">
                <a href="/">
                    5
                </a>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox">
                <a href="/">
                    4
                </a>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox">
                <a href="/">
                    3
                </a>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox">
                <a href="/">
                    2
                </a>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox">
                <a href="/">
                    2A
                </a>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class=" cf_sel_opt">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <a href="/">
                    1
                </a>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class=" cf_sel_opt">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <a href="/">
                    00
                </a>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class=" cf_sel_opt">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <a href="/">
                    0
                </a>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <label class=" cf_sel_opt">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <a href="/">
                    Light/Mesh lycra
                </a>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are storing strings in the array, you can use a regex or string operation. 
I assume this will work for you:

```
<?php 
$array = array('<ul>
<li><div class="MY ELEMENT">aaa</div></li>
<li><div class="">bbb</div></li>
<li><div class="">ccc</div></li>
</ul>'); 

$array[] = '<ul>
<li><div class="MY ELEMENT">111</div></li>
<li><div class="">222</div></li>
<li><div class="">333</div></li>
</ul>';

$search_class = "MY ELEMENT";

foreach($array as $e)
{
  $list = explode('<li>', $e);
  foreach($list as $element)
  {
    if(strstr($element,$search_class))
     {
       $results[] = $element;
     }
  }
}

var_dump($results);
?>
```

Here is the live output https://eval.in/836611 ;)

Comment: thx for answer @MuratBa, but your code does not work for me. I modified my post and gave it exactly the values PHP returns to me. I apologize, obviously I added an inaccurate statement. What in this case?

Comment: Hi @MuratBa. The problem is that the function EXPLODE  <li> does not work properly and always returns the standard list <ul><li>. As far as I understand correctly, it should return only what is between <li> in this case. Can you tell me what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was working a lot. ;) can you provide me your exact PHP array please and the result you expect? Ps. Yea, that code should give everything inside that list!

Comment: hi, I created new post (sorry) and there I gave the exact output https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45299023/php-explode-ulli-and-select-only-tags-with-class

Answer (score 0):

You should overthink your method imho. Seems like it is a typical DOM-Issue. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model )

Anyways.. you have an Array and you can get the affected Array-Elements with preg_grep().

```
$results = preg_grep('/class="MY ELEMENT"/is', $input);
```

If you access this Results with DOM it will be easy to get the desired Scriptparts.